# Migrate Mongodb to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, migrate

I use Mongodb to get query results from an online web server and convert collections on it to a `.txt` file. Then I use a dropbox account to sync this txt to my main PC to process data inside it and insert the new data into SQL Server. As you can guess this process is too risky to me because dropbox connection may corrupted somehow and its not healthy and not make sense.

I've just found that there was a way to replicate a mongodb db in a server to another one. But I don't know if it's reasonable.

So can you guys tell me if there is a way to migrate a mongodb database to SQL Server which is located to different server?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way probably is to write simple application that can connect both SQL and MongoDB servers and read data from MongoDB and insert it into SQL Server. It is very simple process:

- Connect MongoDB Server
- Read Data
- Connect SQL Server
- Insert Data

You can find list of programming languages supporting Mongo [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/). All of the listed technologies support SQL Server connections as well.

Comment: thanks for reply. My mongodb has got about 1M data and i need something like BULK insert to SQL SERVER which i already use it by txt that comes from dropbox. I'm using c# to process data's inside mongo db to my remote server's ms sql server anyway.